# Nginx serving css, but just half of it

Tags: django, nginx

I just upload a website Django application on AWS using NGINX and uwsgi protocol. The website is running fine but only part of the minified version of CSS is loaded. More specificaly the part of the css which configures the footer section of the page doesn't load. But all the CSS is in the same file.

NGINX conf file is something like this:

```
`upstream django {
    server unix:///home/ubuntu/django-apache-nginx-uwsgi-vps-ubuntu   /mysite.sock; 
}

server {
    listen      8000;
    server_name example.com;
    charset     utf-8;

    client_max_body_size 75M; 

    location /media  {
        alias /home/ubuntu/django-apache-nginx-uwsgi-vps-ubuntu/media; 
    }

    location /static {
        alias /home/ubuntu/django-apache-nginx-uwsgi-vps-ubuntu/static;
    }

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /home/ubuntu/django-apache-nginx-uwsgi-vps-ubuntu/uwsgi_params; 
    }
}
`
```

Comment: if its all in the same file, then you might have a caching problem., also check the file for EOF's

Comment: If you made changes to the css file (or any modification inside your static directory), don't forget to run `./manage.py collectstatic` again.